# Fiddler intercept http Requests TO my Weblogic server?

Tags: web-services, soap, weblogic, fiddler

I have a app running on WebLogic, which exposes some web services for an external client to call.  I do not control the WebLogic app, but would like to see what requests it is getting.  Is there any good way to do this with Fiddler?

Comment: I would recommend using [*wireshark*](http://www.wireshark.org/)

Comment: Yep, that did the trick.  If you post this as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using [*wireshark*](http://www.wireshark.org/) (previously known as Ethereal).